# How to update dictionary in multiple functions

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to update dictionary in multiple functions. With each function new Key:Values are added to dictionary and finally main dictionary should be updated. Can anyone shed some light on. I have tried below

```
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

def one():
    thisdict['new1'] = 'newvalue1'
    return thisdict

def two():
    thisdict['new2'] = 'newvalue2'
    return thisdict

print(thisdict)
```

I am getting below output:

```
{'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang', 'year': 1964}
```

but I want output to print

```
{'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Mustang', 'year': 1964, 'new1': 'newvalue1', 'new2': 'newvalue2'  }
```

Comment: You are not calling the functions in your code, how do you expect them to update the dict if they are not called?

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are not calling your functions that are supposed to be altering your Dict. Without calling them nothing will be updated.

Try calling them like so:

```
thisdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

def one():
    thisdict['new1'] = 'newvalue1'
    print('one, changed')

def two():
    thisdict['new2'] = 'newvalue2'
    print('two, changed')

one()
two()

print(thisdict) # will give you what you want
```

You initially had the functions returning the `thisdict` value, but from what I could see this is unnecessary as you have a global `thisdict` variable that simply needs to be changed. This is why I added the print statements so you can see how things are being altered.

Comment: Is there a way to update the dictionary without calling function? As I have nearly 5 functions and value of dictionary values are updated in each function I am trying to call all 5 functions to update the dictionary.

Comment: @user29496 Yeah, you can do `thisdict['new1'] = 'newvalue1'` outside of a function. Why do you think you need to use a function?

Comment: i need to add the result of function to dictionary and use it in teardown script.

Comment: @user29496, please add more data to your question, you note nothing of a teardown script or what it is for. You can very easily update dictionaries using the  return values or `update()` or probably multiple other ways. If you do not define what you need and why explicitly, you do not have a solid question asked. Ask for what you need, without that this becomes an XY problem (i.e. abstracting what you actually are looking for)